# How to have Freemarker use java.util.Date instead of org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, freemarker

This is probably a question for people close to Alfresco, as it is a bit specific.

I have added a custom aspect to site on creation, and it holds a property of type date:

`<type>d:date</type>`

Now, I'm extending the **site.lib.ftl** file to display this date:

`"startdate": "<#if site.node.hasAspect("my:customAspect")>${siteNode.properties["my:customAspectDate"]?string("yyyy-MM-dd")}</#if>",`

Since I could not get to a site.node in the macro itself, I've extended the macro parameter list:

`<#macro siteJSONManagers site siteNode roles>`

so I can call it from **site.get.json.ftl** as well as **person.sites.get.json.ftl**:

`<@siteLib.siteJSON site=site siteNode=siteNode />`

Now, for site.get.js I prepare the sitenode in javascript:

`model.siteNode = site.node; // or the same with site.getNode;`

My date is parsed correctly.
However, when calling the macro from **person.sites.get.json.ftl**, I cannot prepare the site.node in javascript controller, so I do it instead in freemarker (by calling it directly):

`<@siteLib.siteJSONManagers site=site siteNode=site.node roles=roles/>`

In using this form, I get this exception:

`"09090011 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 09090096 Error during processing of the template 'Expected method. siteNode.properties[\"my:customAspectDate\"]?string evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 59, column 71 in org\/alfresco\/repository\/site\/site.lib.ftl.'. Please contact your system administrator."`

If I just display this scallar (${siteNode.properties["my:customAspectDate"]}), I get org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate as a string in my resulting JSON:

`"startdate": "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate@7a6e5e2e",`

I can repeat that by setting the same parameter for siteNode in the **site.get.json.ftl**.
I can even repeat it if I use siteNode.properties["cm:created"].

It seems to me that when javascript controller creates a model object from a node, the created date props get created as java.util.Date, or whatever Freemarker uses, and that when Freemarker itself creates that property, it will be turned into org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate.

Can somebody please point out how can I could improve my code so that it shows the date? What can I use so that my calls get the same values?

I am using Alfresco from SVN HEAD if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi You could use the following within Freemarker:

```
${siteNode.properties["my:customAspectDate"]?date?string("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

Alfresco does that in the Activities Dashlet:

> activity-list.get.html.ftl

Comment: Isn't `siteNode.properties["my:customAspectDate"]` already a date (as opposed to a string that looks like a date)? Because then the `?date` part is redundant.

Comment: Yes it's a date, but not the right date object Freemarker needs/wants, so like sometimes in Javascript you need to append an empty String "" to an object to become a string. That doesn't mean that the object was or wasn't a string.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that where the asker answers his own question, `nodeR.properties["my:customAspectDate"]?string("yyyy-MM-dd")` works for him. That means `nodeR.properties["my:customAspectDate"]` is already the kind of date that FreeMarker understands. If it was an `org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate`, `?date` wouldn't work anyway, because its string value is something like `"org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate@7a6e5e2e"`, which can't be parsed as a date.

Comment: Yes that's right, but that's only in the context within freemarker, but if you check his code than he's looking up a site within freemarker by a Path which is much slower than just using the "best practise" javascript like Alfresco does in their own code. But the problem is than that de date gets converted, so the fix is to just convert it back to freemarkers own date and then format it. It's being used throughout Alfresco, so I assume that's the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

If people often work with Rhino in Alfresco, then this should be fixed there. What's happening is this: FreeMarker templates don't directly use `java.util.Date` for dates, they use `freemareker.template.TemplateDateModel`. FreeMarker has a setting called `object_wrapper`, which is an object that converts objects to `freemareker.template.Template{Something}Model`-s. Apparently, the object-wrapper that Alfresco uses doesn't know `org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate`, and it converts it to a `TemplateScalarModel` (which is FreeMarker's string type) using `toString()`. Hence then `yourDate?string`, where `yourDate` is a FreeMarker string (`TemplateScalarModel`) will just evaluate to the same string as `yourDate`, and thus the `(...)` after it will fail (you can't call a string). When `yourDate` is a FreeMarker date (a `java.util.Date` properly converted to `TemplateDateModel`), `yourDate?string` evaluates to the formatter method, hence the `(...)` after it can call it.

So, if working with Rhino (JavaScript) objects is common in Alfresco, they should extend their `ObjectWrapper` to recognize Rhino objects. Maybe all they need to do is mixing in `freemarker.ext.rhino.RhinoWrapper`.

Comment: this is why i think it is incossistent. thanks for the extensive explanation, though.

Answer (score 1):

Aaaaaand to answer my own question, in case somebody else bumps into this wall for two days too:

```
<#assign nodeR=companyhome.childByNamePath["Sites/" + site.shortName] />
"startdate": "<#if nodeR.hasAspect("my:customAspect")>${nodeR.properties["my:customAspectDate"]?string("yyyy-MM-dd")}</#if>",
```

Like I said on the [forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=46643) as well, I don't know why it works this way and not the other.